# Maximizing Differential Entropy with Limited Support and Power Budget Constraint and Expected sigmoid constraint

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory, entropy

### Context

I am delving into the study of probability distributions and their entropy, with a particular focus on identifying a distribution that maximizes entropy under specific constraints. An area of interest is the application of the sigmoid function, widely recognized in logistic regression and neural networks, to this problem. The sigmoid function is defined as:

$$
\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}
$$

### Problem Statement

Given a random variable $X$, I am faced with the following constraints:

- The expectation of $X^2$, denoted as $E[X^2]$, is constrained by a constant $E$.
- The expectation of the sigmoid of $X$, $E[\sigma(X)]$, is limited to a maximum value $D$, where $D$ is within the range $(0, 1)$.

The goal is to find the probability distribution of $X$ that achieves maximum differential entropy under these constraints.

### Hypothesis

My initial conjecture is that a binomial distribution with equal probabilities of success and failure might be the optimal solution for maximizing entropy subject to the aforementioned constraints. This intuition is grounded in the discrete nature and inherent symmetry in the probabilities of the binomial distribution, suggesting it might favor higher entropy under such conditions.

### Questions

1. What is the specific form of the probability distribution that maximizes entropy subject to the constraints $E[X^2] \leq E$ and $E[\sigma(X)] \leq D$? with limited size of constellation of xsupport.
2. What methodologies or approaches exist for identifying such a distribution?
3. Does my hypothesis regarding the binomial distribution hold any merit in this context? If not, which distribution could potentially be more suitable?
4. I would greatly appreciate any references to literature or theoretical discussions relevant to information theory and constrained optimization in relation to this problem.

Your expertise and insights on this intriguing issue would be incredibly valuable to me. Thank you in advance for your guidance and assistance.

Answer (score 3):

It’s not entirely clear to me whether you mean discrete or differential entropy, but in either case there’s no maximum because in either case a uniform distribution with values below $D$ can be chosen with arbitrarily large entropy by extending the support towards $-\infty$, increasing the number of points / the length of the interval and thus the entropy.

Comment: Thank you, I mean differential entropy, with also power budget constraint $E{X^2}<E$

Comment: I've revised my question to better reflect the discussion. From what I understand based on the insights provided, it seems the entropy could be maximized by expanding the support towards $-\infty$. However, due to constraints related to the power budget, extending to infinity isn't feasible, so we instead consider extending to $\pm\sqrt{E}$.

Yet, this raises a question: if we have the condition that $E{\text{sigmoid}(x)} = D$, how should we approach achieving maximum entropy within this framework?

Comment: @AlirezaGhazavi: The differential entropy of a discrete distribution is $-\infty$, so a binomial distribution can’t maximize differential entropy.

Comment: so what can maximize the entropy in this case? I mean 2-PAM distribution. with 2 impulse (delta dirac function) in both sides.

Comment: @AlirezaGhazavi: Yes, the differential entropy of a Dirac delta is $-\infty$.

Comment: yes, thats true, what about discrete entropy?

Comment: @AlirezaGhazavi: There’s no maximum for the discrete entropy even with the constraint on $\mathsf E\left[X^2\right]$ because you can put as many equiprobable discrete values near the same value as you like, so you can make the discrete entropy arbitrarily high (if there’s any solution at all, i.e. if $D\gt\frac1{1+\mathrm e^{\sqrt E}}$).

Comment: But I have limited number of constellation points or xsupport values.

Comment: @AlirezaGhazavi: It seems the question keeps shifting. I’ve lost track of which of your answers in the comments above still apply. Please edit the original post to formulate a complete and coherent question. Note that if you stick with your original answer that you mean differential entropy, then together with the constraint on $\mathsf E\left[X^2\right]$ that yields a well-defined optimization problem that can be solved using variational calculus with Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: I have editted my question. yes exactly, how can I model and state my problem, does any analytical solution exist?

Comment: @AlirezaGhazavi: The question still doesn’t say whether you’re considering discrete or differential entropy. In the comments above you switched between the two.

Comment: editted. I am seeking for maximizing differential one.